# VB.Net form as part of desktop

Tags: vb.net, desktop

I've spent a while searching around and I can't find a solution to this:

I have a transparent, borderless form that displays a clock. I can load this just fine, but I want the clock to be part of the desktop, so it cannot take focus, is behind other applications, and is not hidden with Win+D (similar to applications like RainMeter).

I need the solution to work with VB.Net (I'm using 2010)

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following codeproject article:

[Application Desktop Toolbars](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx)

It seems to do what you require.

> This article is about Application Desktop Toolbars, which are
>   applications that can align to the screen much like the taskbar. The
>   article will develop a base class for developing such apps.

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for. The article creates a toolbar that resizes the desktop around it. I wanted a way of adding my form to the desktop over the wallpaper like Rainmeter does, so it stays behind other windows and doesn't get hidden by Win+D/Win+M